# Comparing specific properties in elements of an array of objects

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an array of Passengers as follows:

```
Passenger[] passengers = new Passenger[5];
```

Here is the definition for Passenger:

```
public class Passenger{
    int id;
    int fromId;
    int toId;
}
```

I want to find the passengers whose "to" and "from" properties are matching; for example if John has fromID = 3, and Jerry has toID = 3, then I can put them together and add them to a *List* of "pairedPassengers". I already have a O(n^2) solution as follows, but what is a more efficient way?

```
public class PairedPassengers{
 int id1;
 int id2;
}

public class MainClass{
 public static void main(String[] args){
    List<PairedPassengers> pairedPassengers = new ArrayList<PairedPassengers>();

    for (int i=0; i<passengers.length(); i++){ //length of the original array with all data
      for (int j=i; j<passengers.length(); j++){
       if (passengers[i].fromId == passengers[j].toId && passengers[i].toId == passengers[j].fromId){
        PairedPassengers pPassengers = new PairedPassengers(); //creating a new object to put pairing passengers into
        pPassengers.id1 = passengers[i].id;
        pPassengers.id2 = passengers[j].id;
        pairedPassengers.add(pPassengers);
       }
      }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at using a `HashMap<Integer, List<PairedPassengers>>` structure. Key being the `PairedPassengers.fromId`. Populate the map first in `O(n)` time and then iterate over all of the `PairedPassengers` matching the `toId` in `O(n)` time.

Comment: @NTL if there are duplicate IDs, then the Map of Lists solution is still O(n^2) in the worst case simply because the number of pairs is O(n^2) in the worst case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Map` to look up a `Passenger` by their `to` field. The `get` and `put` methods on a `HashMap` are both O(1) time, so this algorithm has an overall complexity of O(n).

```java
Map<Integer, Passenger> to = new HashMap<>();
for(Passenger p : passengers) {
    to.put(p.toId, p);
}

List<PairedPassengers> paired = new ArrayList<>();

for(Passenger q : passengers) {
    Passenger p = to.get(q.fromId);
    if(p != null) {
        paired.add(new PairedPassengers(p, q));
    }
}
```

You should also write a suitable constructor for the `PairedPassengers` class.

I'm assuming here that each passenger is supposed to be paired with only one other passenger in a unique way, so there aren't duplicate `to` or `from` fields. If there are such duplicates, then you will need a `Map<Integer, List<Passenger>>` to store a list of passengers with each `to` value. The solution will still be O(n) time in the best case, but it will be O(n²) in the worst case because there can be a quadratic number of pairs to find.